# Apply custom filter on the entries in admin control panel using custom plugin in craft cms 3.5

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, events, security, hook

I was referring to [Filter entries in the CP based on custom permission](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/filter-entries-in-the-cp-based-on-custom-permission) and [Filter entries in the CP based on custom permission](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/filter-entries-in-the-cp-based-on-custom-permission)

It seems onBuildElementsQuery was available only in 2.x.
Is there any alternative for craft 3.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!!! Used ElementQuery::EVENT_AFTER_PREPARE